# Union alternate to make query more efficient. Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

Below is my query

```
    Select 
count(t.prid)
 from
(select 
    pr.prid
from
    jcp
inner join pr ON pr.prid = jcp.prid
where
    jcp.custid = 123 union select 
    pr.prid
from
    jcl
inner join pr ON pr.prid = jcl.prid
where
    jcl.custid = 123) as t
```

is there any way to make it more efficient?  this query is inside some function and executing 1000s of time. so making it slow.

Comment: Is there a table, where custid is a primary key?

Comment: It would be useful, if you just describe us your tables(like in [sqllfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/)) and your goal! , then we could even discover a simpler query.

Comment: Might it be quicker to just get seperate counts from jcp and jcl and then add them together in php (or whatever language the function is in?) Two very quick queries might be better performance than one with a bad union.

Comment: Also, why is you function doing this thousands of times? Perhaps you should also consider doing one query that gets the whole dataset. A sort of `select custid, count(prid) from ... group by custid`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your query appears to be combining two very different types of data in your 'union' - the first part being the count of an ID, and the second being the literal ID - so I would question whether this is really doing what you intend it to do as written.  However, just taking it at face value, you could eliminate the subquery in the first part as follows:

```
SELECT COUNT(pr.prid)
FROM jcp
    INNER JOIN pr 
    ON pr.prid = jcp.prid
WHERE jcp.custid = 123
```

I can't say how much that would help your performance without knowing the context of your data, but it certainly wouldn't hurt.

Given the difference in the two data sets, it doesn't appear possible to avoid the union if you want to force these two different bits of data into the same column.  If you were to put them into different columns, you could probably avoid the union.